# How do I delete a file in terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

Sorry I am a newbie in Terminal.

When creating a PHP file in the terminal on Ubuntu using the following code:

```
sudo nano /var/www/filename.php
```

I successfully create a PHP file. However I have no idea how to delete it. Any suggestions?

Comment: You really couldn't find an answer to this by searching the web?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use:

```
sudo rm /var/www/filename.php
```

`rm` stands for "remove files or directories".

Comment: you can use "unlink" as well in place of "rm"